# azure cdn - multiple end points?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Can you have a single azure CDN instance configured for multiple items?
i.e I currently have a web role in a cloud service...the web role uses an azure storage account to store all images etc.
I currently have the azure CDN configured to the cloud service (prompted on create) - so now I have my various scripts and css etc on the CDN. I would like to also have all images/assets from the storage account on cdn too and was wondering if this could be done from this one CDN or would I need to create another CDN just for the images etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure by what you meant by "same cdn" but you can use the same CDN profile to have two CDN endpoints. One pointing two the cloud service root. The other one to the images contents blob. Kindly find below two links that describe the two approaches both for the cloud service and the storage below.

Hope this helps!

Storage: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn/

Cloud Services: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-cloud-service-with-cdn/

Comment: Cheers,will have a look through :)